# How can I stream an XPS document to a browser and embed it in a webpage?

Tags: asp.net, stream, binaryfiles, xpsdocument

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to go about this.  Any input is appreciated!

Currently, I have an ASP.NET MVC application.  On the client, I have a link with an ID of an XPS document.  When the user clicks the link, they are taken to a page with details about the document.  In addition to this information, I wish to display the document along side of this information, in the same page.

On the server side, once I have the ID, I can get the document, serialized as a byte array, from the database.  The question is, what's the *best* way to get that serialized document into the webpage?

I would SEVERELY prefer not having to drop that document into the file system and then munge together a file path.  I would like to be able to stream the document to the browser as a content type of "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument".

I've tried using a web control to handle this (can't write binary out), thought about creating a HTTP handler to do this (no idea where to start), and have fuddled around with a couple other ways to get the document stream to the browser.

In addition, there is also the question of how to embed the document in the web page.  Do I use an EMBED tag?  Or an Object?  Or do I use an iframe and set the source to point to whatever delivers the document?

Again, I don't expect a solution wrapped up in a bow.  I'm looking for some advice on how to go about this.  And, while this question is about xps documents, it applies to any application that streams a binary file that is to be hosted in a browser (PDFs, etc).

---

Okay, as for displaying in the browser, one word:  Silverlight.  That's solved.  I still have the issue of figuring out the best way to send it from the server to the browser.

---

Strike that.  It appears Silverlight isn't advanced enough to display an XPS document just quite yet.  I'm thinking about an iframe pointing to a http handler now...  The iframe works.  Too bad it throws the entire thing down the pipe.  I suppose I could always strip off the first page and send that puppy...

---

Wow.  No need for a HTTP handler.  A custom ActionResult in MVC is all you need.  How friggen awesome is that?

Comment: Good find on the ActionResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to provide the document as a link (target="_blank") from the details page.  This has several advantages:

- You don't need to retrieve and stream the entire doc unless the user asks for it.
- On my system at least IE is already registered as the default XPS viewer, so by giving the doc it's own window you avoid the whole question of how to embed it.
- It makes it simple to provide a streaming source for the document: just use an HTTP Handler with an ID for a query string parameter.

Even if you don't like that idea, definitely go with an HTTP Handler for transmitting document.  It's real simple to do:  when you create a new HTTP Handler in Visual Studio it should give you a nice page with all the busy-work done already.

Comment: If done right, I don't have to stream the entire thing because XPS documents are built to deliver their content on demand.  The document contains individual packages that are managed by a package store.  Individual packages are delivered when needed.  Its pretty sweet.

Comment: Hey, me, its too bad that won't work.  Silverlight isn't mature enough yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Silverlight control capable of displaying XPS documents. See http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/announcement-document-toolkit-for-silverlight/ for more